# What are the basic privileges needed to acces user_privileges table from information_schema database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

I want to know the minimum set of privileges requires to be able to see all the entries inside user_privileges table as a root user would see without granting root privileges.

If I grant select privileges on all the tables of mysql database, I am able to see all the entries but I need to know the minimum set of table that I would need to grant select privileges on, for all the information.

Basically, I want to extract out number of privileges granted to each user present in the database with minimum privileges.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, this is a question for DBAs.

Comment: [select on mysql.*](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/ea7d2e2d16ac03afdd9cb72a972a95981107bf51/sql/auth/sql_authorization.cc#L5445) is the only criteria.  [dba exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) for purely DB questions next time. Welcome to SO and soon to be DBA exchange.